# Ansible win_file can not create a directory on a partitioned drive?

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.11.0

I created an`I:` disk partition on my Windows 2019 host under `jenkins` user, who is an admin. Logged in as `jenkins`, I can create a directory on the partition.

I have this Ansible task that simply tries to create the same directory structure, like this

```
- name: "Create data directory {{ pg_data_dir }}"
  win_file:
    path: "{{ pg_data_dir }}" # I:\pgdata\13
    status: directory
```

I get ...

```
TASK [postgresql : Create data directory I:\pgdata\13] ********************************
task path: /path/ansible/exa-playbooks/roles/postgresql/tasks/install_postgresql.yml:21
redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.win_file to ansible.windows.win_file
Using module file /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/3.3.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections/ansible/windows/plugins/modules/win_file.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<10.227.xx.xx> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: jenkins on PORT 5986 TO 10.227.xx.xx
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
fatal: [10.227.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "path I:\\pgdata\\13 will not be created"
}
```

Any clues?

**UPDATE**

For now, I just changed my task to this, but the above issue persists.

```
- name: "Create data directory {{ pg_data_dir }}"
  win_shell:
    mkdir "{{ pg_data_dir }}" # I:\pgdata\13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh on me. It should be `state`, not `status`, like this

```
- name: "Create data directory {{ pg_data_dir }}"
  win_file:
    path: "{{ pg_data_dir }}" # I:\pgdata\13
    state: directory
```